# What's the meaning of "justify" in this context and what is it he wants to say here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

https://youtu.be/mwEXxC_rIHA?t=3m5s

> Tom Lee says that Bitcoin is no different from Facebook or Google.
>
> If you ask a baby boomer, "Can you **justify** the value of anything that's a digital business? They probably don't accpet that Facebook, Google, Netflix, Amazon, Apple. (I mean) these are the largest companies in the S&P500. And they're primarily digital businesses built almost purely on digital trust."

I don't get the exact meaning of "justify" here, and thus having difficulty understanding what he says next as well. And I'm also not sure why he mentions "baby boomer"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

justify has a specific meaning in a religious context, but here is used in the other sense

> show or prove to be right or reasonable

The thrust of the argument is that the value of companies such as those mentioned is not based on traditional physical things (factories, mines, oil-wells), but on things that only exist in the digital world. So, the argument goes, Bitcoin is just another digital thing; if we are prepared to ascribe high value to Google, then why not to Bitcoin?

The use of baby boomer (people such as myself, who are now reaching retirement age but who have seen the growth of these digital companies, and invested our money in their shares) is to point to a group of people who accept the value of Facebook, Amazon and Apple, and yet he claims can probably **not** justify (explain, give reasons for) their value. Why then do such people disrespect Bitcoin?

My guess that he would contrast the baby-boomer with a younger generation more accepting of Bitcoin.

For what it's worth, this baby boomer thinks that the argument is not very strong. I don't own Google and Apple shares because of digital trust but because they make money by selling things I understand - computers and advertising :-)